# Can't install Matplotlib for Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Every time I try to install Matplotlib. I am trying to install the Windows 64 bit for Python 2.7 I have Python 2.76 downloaded. And it says

Python 2.7 which was required was not found in registry

but I have Python in C:\Python27

Any idea why this is or what I can do to get MatPlotLib installed?

Comment: Are you installing it with Pip?

Comment: I am using Windows 7. So not pip.

Comment: Pip is a package manager, it can easily install python libraries for you.

Answer (score 0):

Silly question. But was it put in the right folder and was it put in the folder that python will look for it in? Also try having a look for it yourself and if it's not there then try using a different version or use an installer like people above said.

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib will work after you install all these packages as detailed below:

numPy:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.0/numpy-1.9.0-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download

numpy is currently available for Windows only in 32-bit format

Checking your numpy:

import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10)

a

dateutil and six:

cmd

cd\

cd python27\scripts

pip2.7 install python-dateutil

This should install six as well

pyparsing and pytz:

pip2.7 install pyparsing

pip2.7 install pytz

matplotlib:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.3/windows/matplotlib-1.4.3.win32-py2.7.exe/download?use_mirror=liquidtelecom

Checking your matplotlib:

from matplotlib import pyplot

pyplot.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16])

pyplot.show()